# Does SVG path element support a lifting of the pen?

Tags: html, svg

In SVG there are different commands used such as move pen, draw line, draw curve and so on like so:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>

</svg>
```

Is there a command that lifts the pen and then sets the pen down again? As an example, is there a single value of SVG path data that would draw parallel lines that do not intersect inside a single path element?

More info on [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) on MDN.

Comment: Sure, it's the M command. You have one in your path already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RobertLongson for pointing this out.

I can use move more than once. In this case it is in the middle of the statement.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path d="M10 10 H 90 M 10 90 H 90" stroke="red"
  stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>

</svg>
```